# Specifying a param from a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Consider a `PersonController` which has a `list` action. A user can choose to list all people, or only males or females; currently, to do that, they'd have to go to `/people/m` or `/people/f`, corresponding to the route

```
map.list_people "people/:type",
  :conditions => { :method => :get },
  :requirements => { :type => /a|m|f/ },
  :defaults => { :type => 'a' }
```

(`/people/a` works the same as just `/people/`, and lists all people).

I want to change my routing so that I could have two routes, `/males/` and `/females/` (instead of `people/:type`), both of which would go to `PersonController#list` (DRY -- aside from an extra parameter to what's being searched, everything else is identical), but will inherently set the `type` -- is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map.with_options(:controller => "people", :action => "index") do |people|
  people.males 'males', :type => "m"
  people.females 'females', :type => "f"
end
```

Then you should be able to do `males_path` or `males_url` to get the path for this, and I'm sure you can guess what you do to get the path to females.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't find it in the routing guide. Thanks!